# How to insert multiple records into Redis Hash using Lua Script in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, lua, redis

How to insert multiple records into Redis Hash using Lua Script in Node.js

I have the below code which inserts using multi, exec.   How to change it using lua script

```
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) 
        {
            // results variable contains data fetched from MySQL db
            results.forEach(function (item) 
            {
                redisClient.hmset('sections:' + item.section_id, item);
            });

            redisClient.exec(function (err, replies) 
            {
                if (err) 
                {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                else 
                {
                    if (results.length == replies.length)
                        console.log("Sections Inserted");
                }

                resolve();
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***OP said***

> yes I got it but which is an appropriate method for previous example.
>   I just want to know in terms of performance

Since original poster has said me that the goal of the question is knowing if the sample application layer JavaScript code would be better implemented in Lua to execute it in Redis, I've an answer for the whole question: **no**.

Redis is an in-memory store (it can be stored in disk too, but the real-time data access is done against the memory instead the disk), and also Redis isn't multi-threaded in terms of processing requests, it seems like original poster's scenario may work better as it's presented in the question: using application layer code.

If you issue 1k read or write operations using Lua, you're going to block the entire Redis server until it finishes the Lua script execution, while if you issue these operations from the application layer, they will end up in 1k requests to Redis, but they're yet small enough to let other operations coming from other clients be processed.

Since accessing memory is blazing fast, you should prefer executing commands from the application layer and use Lua scripts just when you want to implement very small operations that involve two or more Redis commands. For example, the following sequence could be implemented in Lua:

```
MULTI
hset users 1 "matias"
sadd users 1
EXEC
```

And call it using `EVALSHA`.

Comment: in my scenario I have around 7 to 8 thousand records which needs to be inserted using hmset and same operation needs to repeat every 3 or 4 minutes. So I was thinking which would be appropriate.

Comment: @Sharath I've already answered your question, including your comment :D